# sonar-collapsible if statements

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, sonarqube, pmd

I am getting the exception "collapsible if statement".

Through the sonar in the following code.

```
if(getSomething().equals(getSomething()){
  if(getsomehing.contains(getSomething()){

  }
}
```

Collapsible if statements These statements could be combined.

What is the meaning of this metric?

Answer (score 10):

see the pmd explanation for this: http://qa.nuiton.org/sonar/rules/show/pmd:CollapsibleIfStatements?layout=false

PMD/Sonar identified, that you don't need 2 if statements, but can rather combine it to one using AND/OR opeartors.

this should be OK:

```
if (getSomething().equals(getSomething()) && getsomehing.contains(getSomething())) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first `getSomething` equals your second by string equality, then of course both contain one another ;-)

Comment: this has nothing to do with this pmd rule, this metric works on static code analysis

Comment: @oers I figured if it were a performance analyzer it wouldn't suggest changes that are purely cosmetic. PS detecting code like this is *still* static analysis, just more intelligent than what static analyses are generally.